# How to get all the edges between two vertices in bfs java

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search, bigdata

Currently I'm having only one to one relationship between two vertices. I just want to handle multiple relationships between two vertices. How can I do that?

My current code is :

```
 public Collection<Vertex<V, E>> bfs() {

    Queue<Graph.Vertex<V, E>> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(this.getVertices().size());
    Collection<Vertex<V, E>> queryVertices = new LinkedList<>();
    Vertex<V, E> source = this.vertices.get(0);
    Set<Vertex<V, E>> visited = new HashSet<>();

    visited.add(source);
    queue.add(source);
    queryVertices.add(source);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Graph.Vertex<V, E> v = queue.remove();
        Graph.Vertex<V, E> w;
        while ((w = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(v, visited)) != null) {
            visited.add(w);
            queue.add(w);
            queryVertices.add(w);
        }
    }

    return queryVertices;
}

private Vertex<V, E> getAdjUnvisitedVertex(Vertex<V, E> v, Set<Vertex<V, E>> visited) {

    for (Graph.Edge<V, E> edge : v.edges) {
        if (!visited.contains(edge.getTo())) {
            return edge.getTo();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your Vertex class try to add a HashMap or ArrayList of corresponding nodes. As you add edges add the ids (or some other identifying feature of a Vertex) into the ArrayList/HashMap and then you can simply check the ArrayList/HashMap every time you want to see the nodes that each Vertex is connected to. This will also help you in implementing an efficient addEdge algorithm that doesn't add edges that already exist between nodes. Also remember if you are implementing a directed graph Node A -> Node B != Node B -> Node A, so make sure to not leave out edges in your implementation.